# Visual Studio 2015 - How to stop annoying popup

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Before when I was editing a view or partial view, I could simply do this and just refresh the browser to see the changes.  Now every time I edit a view, VS2015 prompts me with this annoying dialog "Do you want to stop debugging?". When I click No, it allows me to continue but it keeps on popping up each time I do a change.  Anybody any idea how to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. One thing I should have mentioned is that I'm also using DotCover with Continuous Testing switched on. When I switched it off, the problem disappeared.

The thought that it was caused by DotCover didn't occur to me because I used NCrunch before which never caused a problem.  This is possibly due to the fact that NCrunch runs tests in memory while DotCover only runs them on Save.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have verified the VS setting?
You can found it in 
"Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Edit and Continue"

Comment: Yes, I did.  Enable Edit and Continue is on.

Comment: It was working fine yesterday, but yesterday something caused visual studio to stop responding and I rebooted my machine and since then this annoying popup happens.  Configuration is still the same. Never saw this popup happen before, not when updating mvc view cshtml files.